# Wordpress - show all posts + ones with specific tag

Tags: php, filters, tags, sort

I have 3 types of posts as below

1. Normal posts without any tag
2. With "featured" tag
3. With "sold" tag

On a page, I just want to show normal posts + ones with featured tag and don't want to show posts with "sold" tag. How can I do the query for this?

Thanks

Comment: It is always better to post the code, you have already tried. So can you please post the code you have already tried?

Comment: I am writing below

query_posts("orderby=date&order=DESC&tag__not_in=sold");

Comment: please update the same in the question you have asked.

Answer (score 0):

It is not advised to used `query_post()` as it replaces the query of the page with new instance of the query. For general post queries, use `WP_Query` or `get_posts`.

here `tag__not_in` takes `id of the tag and not the slug`, so replace `sold` with the id of the tag **sold**

like

```
$args = array(
    'orderby'=> 'date',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'tag__not_in' => sold_tag_ID
);

$allposts = new WP_Query($args);
```